# Can I use external objects with Marketing Cloud connector?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, lightning-connect

Using Salesforce's Lightning Connect to have access to external objects, can I connect this with Marketing Cloud using the Marketing Cloud connector?

If yes, what are the limitations (if any)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not supported (I've tried). You can only connect to Standard or Custom objects using the Connector.